# Is redirecting mydomain.eu & mydomain.net to mydomain.com using .htaccess spammy?

Tags: htaccess, redirects

A client has asked me to develop their site - they already own 3 domains, `mydomain.eu`, `.net` and `.com`.

They want all the traffic from `.eu` and `.net` to redirect to `.com`. I've explained to them that it is not that relevant as people will search for them in search engines rather than typing in the domain, but they still would like me to do it.

As far as I know this is fine to do from an SEO point of view but I thought I'd just double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is certainly no downside to doing this, so long as the redirections are 301 and the content isn't indexed by search engines as belonging to all three domains (if it is for some reason then you would need to implement rel canonical on the primary domain.

I use this code, as it ensures the site can only be viewed and indexed as a single domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.org.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```